# Select all elements within an element with Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, end-to-end

Is there a solid way to select all the elements *within* an element? Let's assume we have the following structure

```
...
<div class="outer">
     <div class="inner"></div>
     <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
...
```

And the piece of code that selects `outer` for us is the following:

```
outer: { get: function () { return element(by.css(".outer")); } }
```

Now, if I want to select *all* the `inner` divs, with the following code:

```
inner: { get: function () { return this.outer.element.all(by.css(".inner")); } }
```

I get an error saying that element.all is not a function. Is there a good way around this?

Comment: Do you have to do it that way, could you not simply use `by.css(".outer > .inner")`?

Comment: Hi @GillesC, thanks for your comment! That is a valid way, and I could do it like that. However, I would like to follow the DRY-pattern. Let's say I need to test if `.outer` is present, and if the second `.inner` div contains "Some Text". Is there a good solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea you are trying to use is actually correct - it is called "chaining" and [was added in Protractor 0.17.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0170), it's just that you don't need that intermediate `element`. Replace:

```
this.outer.element.all(by.css(".inner"))
```

with:

```
this.outer.all(by.css(".inner"))
```

Also note that there are `$` and `$$` shortcuts for `element(by.css())` and `element.all(by.css())` - if you apply them:

```
outer: { get: function () { return $(".outer"); } }
inner: { get: function () { return this.outer.$$(".inner"); } }
```